# Making a div appear as if it's floating outside of it's container

Tags: html, css, css-float, css-position

I'm trying to get a div (with a background image inside it) to appear to be floating outside of it's container. I'm okay with the image overlapping stuff inside the content div, but I don't want the image or containers overlapping other stuff outside. Nor do I want the image pushing the contents around.

What I'm doing seems pretty hacky and I can fix the overlapping by setting a bunch of custom top and bottom margins but I'm sure there's an easier way to do this.

http://codepen.io/0bsidian/pen/GdwhF

Comment: You would be wise to include the code as part of your question; you won't get many responses with just a link to a code bin.

Comment: It's also not clear what you are trying to do. You don't want overlapping or stuff being moved around.

Comment: I dont understand what you are trying to achieve. Can you post a pic of what you want it to look like?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are setting the parent wrap to have `position:relative`, and the wayward child to have `position:absolute`.

This works, but you are right that there is an easier way. Just set the child to have `position:relative`, then make sure that the parent doesn't have `overflow:hidden`.

Instead of using `relative` or `absolute`, you could just use margins:

```css
body {
    background: #444;
}
section {
    width: 600px;
    margin: 6em auto 0 auto;
}
#container {
    margin-top:50px; /*30px would make it touch the <p> above but not overlap, because the image is moved upwards by 30px. 50px gives you a 20px margin.*/
}
#container #image {
    height: 128px;
    width: 128px;
    background: url(http://www.skrenta.com/images/stackoverflow.jpg) no-repeat;
    background-size: contain;
    float:left;
    margin-left:-30px;
    margin-top:-30px;
}
#container #content {
    margin-top:0px;
    padding: 6em 1em 1em 1em;
    border: 2px solid black;
    background: #ccc;
}
```

```html
<html>
    <body>
        <section>
            <p>Stuff outside of container.</p>
            <div id="container">
                <div id="image"></div>
                <div id="content">
                    <h1>Test One</h1>
                    <p>This is a text box. Insert some text here.</p>
                    <p>More stuff here.</p>
                </div>
            </div>
            <p>Stuff outside of container.</p>
        </section>
    </body>
</html>
```

Answer (score 2):

What you need here might be the idea of `box-shadow`.

```
div {
  box-shadow: 2px 2px 5px #333;
}
```

You can use these parameters of your own. This way you can make the element seem like it is floating over the other element.

For more: https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/box-shadow